# src/main/resources read/write xml file

Tags: xml, file

I'm going crazy ! My project is maven based web project.So I have an xml file is called "defter.xml" which placed under the src/main/resources. I want to read and write this xml file. Firstly, to check up what is the relative path of xml file, I used to

```
String path=getClass().getResource("/defter.xml").getPath();
```

But it throwed the "java.lang.NullPointerException". How can I read and write to this file ?
Please help me !